# Function-scoped variable in PowerShell (with Advanced Methods)?

Tags: powershell, scope, powershell-2.0

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here?

```powershell
function Test-Cmdlet {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [string] $Prepend,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string] $OtherString
    )

    BEGIN 
    {
        if ($Prepend -eq $null) {
            $Prepend = ".."
        }
    }

    PROCESS
    {
        write-host ($Prepend + $OtherString)
    }
}

# success:
PS> @( "ab", "cd" ) | Test-Cmdlet "-"
-ab
-cd

# failure:
PS> @( "ab", "cd" ) | Test-Cmdlet
ab
cd

# should be:
..ab
..cd
```

Why is $Prepend not getting set?

I've tried declaring variables outside the BEGIN/PROCESS blocks, but the interpreter doesn't accept that.

I've tried using: `Set-Variable -Name "Prepend" -Value ".." -Scope 1` 
(and Scope 0, and Scope 2), instead of: `$Prepend = ".."`, but still nothing works.

I'm familiar with `$global:Variable`, but any idea how to get function-scoped variables in a cmdlet with Advanced Methods?

**Edit:**

The solution, as per below, is:

```powershell
function Test-Cmdlet {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [string] $Prepend,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string] $OtherString
    )

    BEGIN 
    {
        $_prepend = $Prepend

        if (!$Prepend) {
            $_prepend = ".."
        }
    }

    PROCESS
    {
        write-host ($_prepend + $OtherString)
    }
}
```

Comment: This bypasses the question all together but could you have not just declared the parameter with a default value? `[string] $Prepend="..",`

Comment: @Matt, yes, but this is just an example problem, the real issue wasn't about setting a default, but changing the parameter in the BEGIN block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to assume that you're using Powershell 2.0 for this. In that version, when you set the value of a parameter in the `Begin` block, it will not retain that value in the `Process` or `End` blocks.

This was changed in Powershell 3.0+.

For v2.0, assign a non-parameter variable the value of the parameter and use that throughout all 3 blocks:

```powershell
function Test-Cmdlet {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [string] $Prepend,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string] $OtherString
    )

    BEGIN 
    {
        if ($Prepend -eq $null) {
            $doPrepend = ".."
        } else {
            $doPrepend = $Prepend
        }
    }

    PROCESS
    {
        write-host ($doPrepend + $OtherString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because by defining `$Prepend` as a parameter an empty string is created so your if condition never applys.
You can check for an empty string instead of checking for `$null` as an alternative.

Regards

Comment: Yes, good point, I normally use `if (!$Parameter) { $Parameter = ... }`

Comment: @SamPorch yep that works too, so was this the problem or does it still not work as expected?

Comment: The central issue was setting the variable in the "Begin" block, but certainly this would have caused problems also.